# How to work with google spreadsheet?

Tags: html, google-sheets

I'd like to create an HTML page based on a google spreadsheet file. Something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cYrhzVauv62x6fk2S04hjAymFDF2CVueCub9ywPm624/htmlview?sle=true#gid=0

How do I extract information from a specific cell? Are there any docs somewhere?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display an HTML page in your Google Spreadsheet. Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

> How do I extract information from a specific cell? Are there any docs
>   somewhere?

Well, to do this you need to know about [Google App Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/). Here are some links which I'd recommend you to read and try. These should help you.

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this at the end of your sheet's url, right after the last slash ( **/** ):

> htmlview?sle=true#gid=0

Random example from a sheet I just found online:

> before
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kKyCazQYtORpjW9c6wAqTAWDNYLXkwoLWS63fxP5fMo/edit#gid=2079014508
>
> after
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kKyCazQYtORpjW9c6wAqTAWDNYLXkwoLWS63fxP5fMo/htmlview?sle=true#gid=0

Can you try clicking on them both to see if that's what you wanted?

Answer (score -2):

If your wanting to display the spreadsheet, try this:

```
<object data="URL" width="600" height="400"> <embed src="URL" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT"></embed></object>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks "how to extract information in a specific cell".

Comment: Thats why I said "If your wanting to..." not, "Do this"